# How to add a helper method that could be used in database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use credentials with database.yml in Rails 6 and the file has lines like this:

```
<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:database, :dev, :username) %>
```

I want to make it a bit nicer/less repetitive to look at by implementing a `credentials` helper method (which would accept just the needed keys).

What's the best place to put such method?